# How to save the same CSV twice at two different places using Apache Camel Route

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am creating one csv and saving it to targeted path - this is working as expected.
But now i need to save one more copy of the same csv on another path.

```
from("{{csv.generation}}")
                .setHeader("dynamicFileName", "Main.csv"))
                .toD("sftp://${properties:ses.sftp.user}@{{ses.sftp.host}}:${properties:${header.country}.sftp.port}${properties:${header.country}.sftp.rdir}?username=${properties:ses.sftp.user}&privateKeyFile={{sftp.prvt.key.path}}&preferredAuthentications=publickey&knownHostsFile={{knownHost.file.path}}&fileName=${header.dynamicFileName}&doneFileName=${header.dynamicFileName}{{cco.files.ready.ext}}")
                .log("target csv file has been saved successfully at ${properties:${header.country}.sftp.rdir} SFTP location")
                .to("{{save.copy.to.another.path}}")
                .log("Created a copy on Fabric {{save.copy.to.another.path}}${header.dynamicFileName}")
                .end();
```

when i executed this getting below -

2022-07-29 09:34:23.491 ERROR 1 --- [ #3 - Multicast] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 5BBCC953F1D3167-0000000000000002 on ExchangeId: 5BBCC953F1D3167-0000000000000002). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: /opt/datafiles/5BBCC953F1D3167-0000000000000002

I believe as the csv file is written to main path its not present on the exchange anymore thats why i am not able to write it to next path.
Could you please help me on how to create copy of the main csv to write on another path ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `multicast` EIP (https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/multicast-eip.html)

```
from("direct:demo")
.multicast()
  .to("file://destination1")
  .to("file://destination2")
.end();
```